# Java: Getting values from GUI

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

In my application user gets to choose "distribution type" for a few parameters and then I create Graph and show it to him. There are 3 different types of these distributions with each of them having its own parameters ( like alpha, beta, probabilities, etc). Each parameter can have either of those distributions.

Here is the screenshot to make it clear, what I'm trying to describe:

[image: screenshot]

Distribution options are contained in CardLayout, that is controlled by combobox.

When user presses the button, I need to instantiate proper domain objects for distributions. Right now, I'm just passing ComboBox item (which is enum) and CardLayouted panel to factory that chooses proper subpanel and instantiates correct object. But it seems wrong to pass around gui objects, also makes factory useless for any other situation.

But I can't think of a better way to instantiate correct object. Probably just one idea:

- Let CardLayouted panel decide which panel is ontop and instantiate
  proper object on request. I wouldnt need any factories for this one. But is it ok for gui object to do this kind of logic? How can I delegate to domain in a proper way?

All suggestions will be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing has generally good support for MVC and pushing or pulling data from a domain object to input / display controls. What I'd do is:

Instantiate the panels you put into the CardLayout with a "blank" domain object as its GUI model. (Or some sort of locator that can retrieve the model from another layer.) Then hook up change notifications on your input components that will update the domain object when the values in the input change.

Then, when it comes to persisting the domain object, just retrieve it from the form panel.

If you need to show the same model value in two controls, they should share the same model. If you need to do updates to an object being displayed from lower layers of the code, you should perform the update on the model instead of / in addition to the domain object.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself! 1+